# cannot find module node:events but node version is 16.6

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js, electron

My code is getting this error with using a html script using discord.js runned by electron(nodeIntergation is true and node is working in html)but I get the error: cannot find module node:events when I search it on web it says upgrade your node to 16.6 but it still don't work on 16.6
[image]

Here is the node -v command to proof [image]

I dont't know why this is happening can someone help?

Comment: Electron likely has a different Node version bundled. You can check from the main process via `console.log("Node version: " + process.versions.node);`

Comment: As snwflk says, it is the bundled version of Electron that matters. But it will not be node version, as events module has been in and stable for ages. E.g. it was there back in version 4 https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v4.x/api/events.html    Can you make a minimal example showing your code that generates the error, and also mention which Electron version you are using.

Comment: @DarrenCook I try to use discord.js@13 and it uses node:events and my electron version is 17.0.1

Comment: @snwflk yes when I chechk the version in electron it says 14.17.0 do you know how can I change it?

Comment: Electron comes with specific Node versions bundled (see the start page of electronjs.org). I don't know of a way to change the Node version Electron uses. I'd suggest you follow @DarrenCook's advice in making a [mre] that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know is this a good solution or gonna cause bugs but when I change some of the code in module's code it just worked(changing node:x to x just an example not real module)thanks to @Darren Cook because the thing he said in the comments make me looking to some documention on node.js and I see the modules start to calling module_name to node:module_name from some version(I guess 16.6)like I said I don't know is this a good solution but worked for me no bugs till this moment